# Jenkins start a job only after completion of multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins

How do I create a job A which only runs when jobs B and C are completed, without  a Jenkinsfile

Comment: You Can Build Triggers to other project and Block JOB A  until JOB B and JOB C are not completed

Comment: @FarhanYaseen a link would be helpful. Or please post an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is probably the [Jenkins Join plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/join) which will allow you to trigger a job (let's call it A) after completion of B and C (that can be done in parallel).

Here is the graphical description of what this plugin do (the red part ;) ) :
[image]